# How to append Ajax Json respond to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I use ajax get a json like this:

```
{"dataStore":"[{\"delete_flag\":\"false\",\"id\":\"74\",\"icon_img\":\"img/a5.jpeg\"}]"}
```

How to append "delete_flag" , "id" , "icon_img" to 3 different places on html ?

Comment: Pure javascript or jQuery

Comment: And what 3 places :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this pure javascript method like below.

The code basically uses [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the element, and [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to set the inside of the element to the value of the object.

This code (and the code using jQuery) both use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the data into the correct object that our code can read. The `[0]` at the end is to select the object we wanted since it would give us an array (and we want an object).

```js
const result = {"dataStore":"[{\"delete_flag\":\"false\",\"id\":\"74\",\"icon_img\":\"img/a5.jpeg\"}]"};
const parsedData = JSON.parse(result.dataStore)[0];

document.getElementById("delete_flag").innerHTML = parsedData.delete_flag;
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = parsedData.id;
document.getElementById("icon_img").src = parsedData.icon_img;
```

```html
<div id="delete_flag"></div>
<div id="id"></div>
<img id="icon_img">
```

Or you can use [jQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/jQuery) (which in my opinion, is much simpler). The code below uses [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to change the inside of the divs to the item from the object, and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the attribute src to the image source you wanted.

```js
const result = {"dataStore":"[{\"delete_flag\":\"false\",\"id\":\"74\",\"icon_img\":\"img/a5.jpeg\"}]"};
const parsedData = JSON.parse(result.dataStore)[0];

$("#delete_flag").html(parsedData.delete_flag);
$("#id").html(parsedData.id);
$("#icon_img").attr("src", parsedData.icon_img);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="delete_flag"></div>
<div id="id"></div>
<img id="icon_img">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

For example:

```js
var json = {"id" : "74"};

$( "#content" )
  .html( "<span>This is the ID: " + json.id + "</span>" );
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use some simple JavaScript parsing:

```js
const jsonData = {"dataStore":"[{\"delete_flag\":\"false\",\"id\":\"74\",\"icon_img\":\"img/a5.jpeg\"}]"};

const parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData.dataStore)[0];

document.getElementById("delFlag").textContent = "Delete Flag: " + parsedData["delete_flag"];
document.getElementById("id").textContent = "ID: " + parsedData["id"];
document.getElementById("img").textContent = "Image: " + parsedData["icon_img"];
```

```html
<p id="delFlag"></p>
<p id="id"></p>
<p id="img"></p>
```

Note that you can't parse the full object `jsonData` because it's not JSON - only the data inside it is JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I've upvoted the other answers, but maybe this will help someone else. On your ajax success function, do something like this:

```
success: function(data){
         // console.log('succes: '+data);
            var delete_flag = data['delete_flag'];
          $('#results').html(delete_flag); // update the DIV or whatever element
        }
```

if you got real fancy, you could create a for loop and put all the json variable you need into an array and create a function to parse them all into their proper elements; you could learn this on your own fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {
  "dataStore": {
    "delete_flag": "false",
    id: "74"
  }
}

$('.flag').html(data.dataStore.delete_flag);

$('.id').html(data.dataStore.id);
```

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Flag: <span class="flag"></span> 
<hr />
ID: <span class="id"></span>
```